# Windsor Func<T> property injection

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container, property-injection

Using Windsor 2.5.2, the following works:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IBar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

To delay creation of IBar, this also works:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Func<IBar> barFactory)
    { 
    }
}
```

However, if I combine property injection with `Func<T>`, the following results in a null reference:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Func<IBar> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make Windsor inject the `Func<IBar>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great question Paul. I'm glad you asked.

For implicitly registered `Func`s Windsor is looking at the property, sees it's optional, and it just doesn't bother trying to get it, since... well - it's optional, so you surely are happy not having the dependency populated.

To have it populated, you either register the factory explicitly

```
container.Register(Component.For<Func<IBar>>().AsFactory().Lifestyle.Transient);
```

or you mark the dependency as required (on `ComponentModel` using `Require` method) which is probably best done via an `IComponentModelConstructionContributor`

Comment: "doesn't bother trying to get it, since... well - it's optional" - in that case why does it resolve IBar? It seems very inconsistent.

Comment: `IBar` is registered, so it gets resolved. There are no special cases and `Func` is treated just like any other components and conforms to the same rules as any other component. And rules are Windsor will not interrogate `ILazyComponentLoader`s for optional dependencies, and that's how the `Func`s get implicitly registered. It actually is consistent although may seem surprising to person coming from Autofac which is behaving differently, having special handling for the _relationship_ types including `Func`s

Comment: For the record, the behaviour is changed in the upcoming version of Windsor (codename Wawel) and is going to work like Paul requested.

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic Just to be clear : this makes sure that the delegate has transient lifestyle, not IBar right? We probably won't need a transient delegate ever.